# Looping through Tensor Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I am a beginner in theano and I'm searching a way to loop through a Tensor.
I can develop the functionality with numpy array's, but my code with Theano won't work.

numpy: code

```
a = np.asarray([[0.1,0.5,0.7,0.9,0,1],
                [0.7,0.5,0.3,0.9,0,7]])

t = np.asarray([[0,1,1],
                [0,1,1]])
def obj(predictions,targets):
pred = predictions.reshape(predictions.shape[0],3,2)
pred = np.vstack(np.argmax(pred[i],axis=1) for i in range(predictions.shape[0]))
som = np.abs(targets - pred)
return np.sum(som)

print obj(a,t)
```

What I tried and doesn't work

```
def obj(predictions, targets):
    pred = predictions.reshape([T.shape(predictions)[0],3,2])
    X = T.matrix("X")
    results = theano.scan(lambda x_i: np.vstack(T.argmax(x_i,axis=1)),sequences=[X])
    compute_elementwise = theano.function(inputs=[X], outputs=[results])
    pred = compute_elementwise(pred)
    som = T.abs_(targets-pred)
    return np.sum(som)/T.shape(predictions)[0]
```

Comment: You can't use `np.vstack` in theano expressions!